# NSStatusBar item in storyboard (OSX)

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, xcode7, statusbar

Is it possible to add a `NSStatusBar` item from storyboard for a desktop app?  Most of the examples i saw online do everything in AppDelegate, but i don't think it's a good idea for a more complex app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't add an `NSStatusItem` effectively in a storyboard. It has no outlets and the storyboard editor doesn't know about any of its properties.

If you want to hang a menu off of your status bar item, you can (as of Xcode 7) create the menu in a storyboard. Drag an `NSMenu` into your Application Scene:

[image: create menu]

Connect the menu to an outlet in your app delegate:

[image: connect menu to outlet]

Finally, create the status item in code, using the menu loaded from the storyboard:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    initStatusItem()
}

private var statusItem: NSStatusItem?

private func initStatusItem() {
    self.statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
    statusItem?.title = "Test Item"
    statusItem?.menu = self.statusItemMenu
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to use AppDelegate for this? Shouldn't NSStatusItem have its own view controller?

Comment: `NSStatusItem` isn't a view, so a view controller would not be appropriate. The status item is associated with the app, not with a specific window or view in the app, so it is appropriate for the app delegate to manage it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies! I wanted a `NSStatusBar` item which would show a view from the storyboard with a popup segue. I know how it can be done programatically, but i wondered whether there is a way to use storyboards.

Comment: You can attach a view to a menu item. You can drag an `NSView` into your Application Scene (the same way I did with the `NSMenu`), then control-drag from a menu item to the view. If you want the menu item to contain a view managed by the `NSViewController`, you have to make that connection in code.